# Can someone help me to write the Oracle SQL query for the following data

Tags: sql, oracle

table1:

| NAME | SAL |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 34 |
| ab | 322 |
| ab_d | 34 |
| ab_d | 322 |
| aa | 34 |
| aa | 322 |
| bb | 34 |
| bb | 322 |
| ac | 65 |
| ac_d | 876 |

table 2:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab | ab_d | aa | bb |
| ac | ac_d | ss | pp |

this table2 also contains multiple rows

case 1: If I use table1.name = ab as a where condition,
the output should be,
ab, ab_d, aa, bb records

select * from table1 t1
where t1.name = 'ab';

| NAME | SAL |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 34 |
| ab | 322 |
| ab_d | 34 |
| ab_d | 322 |
| aa | 34 |
| aa | 322 |
| bb | 34 |
| bb | 322 |

(or)
case 2: If I use table2.col2 = ac_d as a where condition,
the output should be,
ac, ac_d, ss, pp records

select * from table1 t1
where t1.name = 'ac_d';

| NAME | SAL |
| --- | --- |
| ac | 34 |
| ac | 322 |
| ac_d | 34 |
| ac_d | 322 |
| ss | 34 |
| ss | 322 |
| pp | 34 |
| pp | 322 |

I am unable to write query....

Comment: Please help us little bit more with your question: show us your code - the code you have tried. Also, please try to reduce data into data that will show your problem(I think you have given us too omuch data)... Also, I do not understand this: "If I use ab(col1) = ab as a condition the output should be displayed from table 1 data using table 2 column records." so please try to tell us more about your problem...

Comment: Your data and results still seem unclear and confused. For both of your cases, please explain *why* you should get the output you listed. In the second case, where are the numbers for `ss` and `pp` coming from, and why are there rows in the output for everything - for example, why are there two rows for `ac` with 34/322 when there is only one row in table 1, with value 65?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select y.*
from table2 x
join table1 y on y.name in (x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, x.col4)
where 'ab' in (x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, x.col4);
```

Result:

```
 NAME  SAL 
 ----- --- 
 ab    34  
 ab    322 
 ab_d  34  
 ab_d  322 
 aa    34  
 aa    322 
 bb    34  
 bb    322
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=93537edc4178f6d316b47773e2f4f1a4).

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd table is identical to the first table.  Please provide CREATE TABLE scripts with data types, Primary keys and Foreign key constraints.

Looking at the structure of the 2nd table and the values in col2 in the first table I think you are going to need an UNPIVOT command
This will take the 2nd table and use the first column as an entity reference, take the column names from the other columns as use them as attributes and take the column value and use it as the value.
E.g. If you had a table:

```
    Colour    Jan     Feb     Mar
    RED       20      15      12
    BLUE       8       7      15

The UNPIVOT command would produce
    Colour    Month    Amt
    RED       Jan       20
    RED       Feb       15
    RED       Mar       12
    BLUE      Jan        8
    BLUE      Feb        7
    BLUE      Mar       15
```